# ResultSet getDouble() check for EMPTY values

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

ResultSet getDouble() returns 0.0 if a value is NULL in the database.
This can be checked using "ResultSet wasNull()" which returns a boolean to check if the last read value was NULL.

But, my database also holds EMPTY values? These are also converted to 0.0, and I don't find a way to check if a column has been empty.

The picture shows the result before I set the value to NULL. It is "EMPTY". So the wasNull() function does not work for my case.

This question is not about an empty result set, but rather empty values in a column.

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between NULL and EMPTY?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov To be honest.I don't really know. It is a regular MySQL database.

Comment: What's the type of that column? If it is some text type that "empty" value might just be an empty string.

Comment: @Thomas ah! Just found out myself aswell :D Yes, it is indeed a text column, so this is just an empty string. And I can use getString() and check for length() > 0.

Comment: It must be some type of string to be empty like this? A Double would be 0.0 or null.